# Add class to HTML tag (<p>) returns an error

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I´m trying to add a class to HTML tag (`<p></p>`), but when I run the code, it returns an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeydown);

const num_ok = [13, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 190];
const del_ = 46;
const back_ = 8;

function getElementByKeyCode(keyCode) {
  return document.querySelector(`[data-key = '${keyCode}']`); //tag <p></p>
}

function changeColor(keyCode, opts = {}) {
  const element = getElementByKeyCode(keyCode);

  if (opts.num || opts.ok) {
    element.classList.add('green'); //error when keydown
  } else if (opts.del) {
    element.classList.add('red'); //error when keydown
  } else if (opts.back) {
    element.classList.add('yellow'); //error when keydown
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    deactive(element)
  }, 1000);
}

function deactive(element) {
  element.className = "num";
}

function onKeydown(event) {
  if (num_ok.includes(event.keyCode)) {
    changeColor(event, {
      num: true,
      ok: true
    });
  } else if (event.keyCode == del_) {
    changeColor(event, {
      del: true
    });
  } else if (event.keyCode == back_) {
    changeColor(event, {
      back: true
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.num {
  color: #fff;
}
p.red {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
p.yellow {
  color: ffc300;
}
p.green {
  color: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns" id="n1">
  <p class="center normal num" data-key="49">1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `element` is presumably null. Check that `getElementByKeyCode` actually returned an element before attempting to operate on it.

Comment: You are passing whole `event` object into `changeColor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the entire event rather than the event.keyCode when calling changeColor(). I can see that you are only having the required element for num1 key stroke, but you do not have the same for the rest numbers. I am guessing this is only a short version for the question.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeydown);

const num_ok = [13, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 190];
const del_ = 46;
const back_ = 8;

function getElementByKeyCode(keyCode) {
  return document.querySelector(`[data-key = '${keyCode}']`); //tag <p></p>
}

function changeColor(keyCode, opts = {}) {
  const element = getElementByKeyCode(keyCode);

  if (opts.num || opts.ok) {
    element.classList.add('green'); //error when keydown
  } else if (opts.del) {
    element.classList.add('red'); //error when keydown
  } else if (opts.back) {
    element.classList.add('yellow'); //error when keydown
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    deactive(element)
  }, 1000);
}

function deactive(element) {
  element.className = "num";
}

function onKeydown(event) {
  if (num_ok.includes(event.keyCode)) {
    changeColor(event.keyCode, {
      num: true,
      ok: true
    });
  } else if (event.keyCode == del_) {
    changeColor(event, {
      del: true
    });
  } else if (event.keyCode == back_) {
    changeColor(event, {
      back: true
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.num {
  color: #fff;
}
p.red {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
p.yellow {
  color: ffc300;
}
p.green {
  color: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns" id="n1">
  <p class="center normal num" data-key="49">1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the `getElementByKeyCode() {return document.querySelector('[data-key = '${keyCode}']')}` function, now `function getElementByKeyCode(keyCode) {return document.querySelector("p[data-key = n" + keyCode.which + "]")}` and the HTML `<div class="btns" id="n1">
  <p class="center normal num" data-key="n49">1</p>
</div>`